# Using grep command inside case statement

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, unix

So I have this script which im trying to determine the type of the file and act accordingly, I am determining the type of the file using file command and then grep for specific string , for example if the file is zipped then unzip it, if its gzipped then gunzip it, I want to add a lot of different types of file.

I am trying to replace the `if` statements with `case` and can't figure it out

My script looks like this:

```
##$arg is the file itself 

TYPE="$(file $arg)"

if [[ $(echo $TYPE|grep "bzip2") ]] ; then

 bunzip2 $arg

elif [[ $(echo $TYPE|grep "Zip") ]] ; then

  unzip $arg

fi
```

Thanks to everyone that help :)

Comment: Can you show the attempt you made at using a case statement ?

Comment: I don't know how to do it with case statement, I can only find case statement which checks the string inside the variable but not grep a specific word inside the string

Comment: no because I'm trying to write a script that gets a file , then it need to determine the file type , $arg is the file name and $TYPE is the output from file command . so im trying to grep a word inside the $TYPE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grep statement is not working inside case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46581564/grep-statement-is-not-working-inside-case-statement)

---- Anyway apart from readability there is not much reason to use a `case` statement over multiple `if` `elif` statements

Comment: This is part of an exercise and I must do it using case , also this is not very good practice to use 10+ if and elif statements

Comment: `case $TYPE in *bzip2*) ...` -- the `*`s make it match anywhere in the string, just like your current grep usage does. Note that this _does not_ require calling grep 10 times, which would be very bad practice itself.

Comment: By the way, all upper case variable names are used by the shell and system utilities; you should choose lowercase names for your own variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general syntax is

```
case expr in
  pattern) action;;
  other) otheraction;;
  *) default action --optional;;
esac
```

So for your snippet,

```
case $(file "$arg") in
  *bzip2*) bunzip2 "$arg";;
  *Zip*)   unzip "$arg";;
esac
```

If you want to capture the `file` output into a variable first, do that, of course; but [avoid upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

`bzip2` and `unzip` by default modify their input files, though. Perhaps you want to avoid that?

```
case $(file "$arg") in
  *bzip2*) bzip2 -dc <"$arg";;
  *Zip*)   unzip -p "$arg";;
esac |
grep "stuff"
```

Notice also how the shell conveniently lets you pipe out of (and into) conditionals.

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for, thank you very much :)

Comment: Also about the upper case variables, wouldn't it be a problem if a command (e.g. type) and a variable name will be the same ?

Comment: No, those are two distinct namespaces; `type` is unambiguously a command (or function etc) while `$type` is a variable.